# Deploy Solr to Tomcat via Maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, solr, intellij-idea

I'm using Solr to handle search extensively in my project, and I'd like to create a submodule in IntelliJ IDEA that I can deploy standalone as a WAR package or launch via IntelliJ alongside other artifacts with a predefined configuration.

I'm using [this tutorial](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/running-solr-with-maven/) to get me started with Solr and Maven. The only change I made was to remove the Jetty plugin (as I'm deploying to Tomcat instead).

Building the WAR file works as expected, however launching with IntelliJ or by deploying it myself to Tomcat returns this stacktrace:

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load config for solrconfig.xml
>       at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:592)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:657)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:364)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:356)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
>
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or 'solr/collection1/conf/', cwd=/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/7.0.42/libexec/bin
>       at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:322)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openConfig(SolrResourceLoader.java:287)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.Config.(Config.java:116)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.Config.(Config.java:86)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.(SolrConfig.java:120)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:589)
>       ... 11 more
>
> 23Sep13-10:54:34 ERROR(SolrException.java:119)-null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core: collection1
>       at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.recordAndThrow(CoreContainer.java:1150)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:666)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:364)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:356)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
>
> Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load config for solrconfig.xml
>       at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:592)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:657)
>       ... 10 more
>
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or 'solr/collection1/conf/', cwd=/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/7.0.42/libexec/bin
>       at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:322)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openConfig(SolrResourceLoader.java:287)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.Config.(Config.java:116)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.Config.(Config.java:86)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.(SolrConfig.java:120)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:589)
>       ... 11 more

My solr.xml looks like this:

```
<solr persistent="true">
  <logging enabled="true">
    <watcher size="100" threshold="INFO" />
  </logging>
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="${solr.default.core.name}" host="${host:}" hostPort="${jetty.port:}" hostContext="${hostContext:}" zkClientTimeout="${zkClientTimeout:15000}">
    <core name="${solr.default.core.name}" instanceDir="${solr.default.core.directory}" />
  </cores>
</solr>
```

and I have a config.properties file (as outlined in the tutorial) which looks like this:

```
#SOLR PROPERTIES
#Configures the directory used to store the data and configuration of the Solr default core
solr.default.core.directory=todo
#Configures the name of the Solr default core.
solr.default.core.name=todo

#SYSTEM PROPERTIES
#Configures the home directory of Solr
solr.solr.home=target/solr-home/
```

How could I make this easily deployable via Tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question! :)

Basically, to achieve my goal, I needed to do the following:

1. Include the Solr WAR as a dependency in my Maven POM file
2. Extract the default Solr core and configuration (`example/collection1/`) to a subdirectory of my project (I used `cores/collection1`)
3. Add a Java VM argument on launch `-Dsolr.solr.home` to point to the cores directory (`-Dsolr.solr.home=/path/to/my/project/cores`)

It's not entirely self contained (I still need to point to a configuration) but it does seem to work.